# how to get coordinate of image using mouse click when resize window?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I am making Game in openGl which contain start menu screen.Problem is when i click start game button (which is a texture image) game start successfully but when i resize window and then click start game button the texture image coordinates change and game did not start how i prevent to change image coordinates after resize window.

**Here is My Mouse funtion**

```
void mouseClick (int button, int state, int x, int  y)    
{
    if (!menu)
    { 
        xMin = 300, xMax = 400, yMin = 350, yMax = 400;

        if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
        {
            y = height - y;
            if (x >= xMin && x <= xMax && y >= yMin && y <= yMax)
            {
                printf_s("starting 2d Game ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my texture Image code**

```
glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);


        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(300, 350);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f(400, 350);

        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(300, 400);


        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(400,400);

        glEnd();
        glFlush();
```

**Here is my Matrix Projection Code:**

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //gluOrtho2D(0.0, 640.0, 0.0, 440);//dino window
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 640.0, 0.0, 440);//dino window
    //gluOrtho2D(1.0, 1.0, 1.0,1.0);//house window
    //gluOrtho2D(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);//bird window
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    //glViewport(220, 100, 100, 200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is the mouse click coordinates that are changing. You will have to convert your mouse click position (x,y) from viewport coordinates to your drawing coordinates (i.e. Ortho2D coordinates).

Assuming that `width` and `height` variables are provided by the system whenever the window is resized, try the following:

```
x = x/width * 640;
y = (height -y) / height * 440;
```

And then test for the button bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to implement this is to use [selection buffer](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm).

With this, you know which polygon is being clicked. This is not affected by the size of the window.

Comment: Thanks for this unique Suggestion i will surely implement selection buffer (Y)